# Unable to observe Livedata from ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit

I have implemented simple a mobile number login on MVVM design pattern.But the Onchanged function is not called when the response is returned from the server.

**LoginViewModel**

```
public class LoginViewModel extends ViewModel {

private LoginModel login;
private MutableLiveData<LoginResponse> loginresponse = new MutableLiveData<>();
private LoginRepository loginrepository;


public void init() {
    login = new LoginModel();
}


public LoginModel getLogin() {
    return login;
}


public void onLoginClick() {
   if(login.isPhonevalid()){
       HashMap<String,Object> loginObject = new HashMap<>();
       loginObject.put("phonenumber",login.getMobileNumber());
       loginObject.put("apimethod","beatme");
       loginresponse = LoginRepository.getInstance().login(loginObject);
      // loginClick.setValue(login);
      }
}


@BindingAdapter("error")
public static void setError(EditText editText, String errormessage) {
    editText.setError(errormessage);

}


public MutableLiveData<LoginResponse> getLoginresponse() {
    return loginresponse;
}


public String getMobileNo(){
    return login.getMobileNumber();
}
}
```

**LoginRepository**

```
public class LoginRepository {


private static LoginRepository loginRepository;
private Api api;

public static LoginRepository getInstance() {
    if (loginRepository == null) {
        loginRepository = new LoginRepository();
    }
    return loginRepository;
}


public LoginRepository() {
    api = RetrofitService.createService(Api.class);
}


public MutableLiveData<LoginResponse> login(HashMap<String, Object> body) {

    final MutableLiveData<LoginResponse> loginResponse = new MutableLiveData<>();
    api.login(body).enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                loginResponse.setValue(response.body());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            loginResponse.setValue(null);
        }
    });

    return loginResponse;
}

}
```

**LoginActivity**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private LoginViewModel viewModel;
ActivityLoginBinding activityLoginBinding;




boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    activityLoginBinding  = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(LoginActivity.this, R.layout.activity_login);

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel.class);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        viewModel.init();
    }
    activityLoginBinding.setLoginViewModel(viewModel);
    setuploginclick();

}

public void setuploginclick() {
    viewModel.getLoginresponse().observe(this, new Observer<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(LoginResponse loginResponse) {

            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,viewModel.getMobileNo(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, OTPVerify.class);
            i.putExtra("mobileno",viewModel.getMobileNo());
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
}
```

I can see from the log that the data is posted success and the response too is perfect. But assigning value to the livedata "loginresponse" doesn't call observable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `loginResponse` from `ViewModel` and create it in `Repository` then pass repository `loginResponse` to your activity. Check below

```
public class LoginRepository {
    public MutableLiveData<LoginResponse> loginResponse = new MutableLiveData<>();
    ...

    //getter
    public MutableLiveData<LoginResponse> getLoginResponse() {
        return loginResponse
    }
}
```

then in ViewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel extends ViewModel {
    ...

    public MutableLiveData<LoginResponse> getLoginResponse() {
        return LoginRepository.getInstance().getLoginResponse()
    }

    ...

    public void onLoginClick() {
        if(login.isPhonevalid()){
            HashMap<String,Object> loginObject = new HashMap<>();
            loginObject.put("phonenumber",login.getMobileNumber());
            loginObject.put("apimethod","beatme");
            LoginRepository.getInstance().login(loginObject);
            // loginClick.setValue(login);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Change your login function in Repository like below:

```
public void login(HashMap<String, Object> body) {

    api.login(body).enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                loginResponse.postValue(response.body());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            loginResponse.postValue(null);
        }
}
```

Comment: It works but, is this is way to design MVVM pattern?

Comment: why not. I just change the `LiveData` passing methodology nothing extra. You have to `postValue` to those `LiveData` that you actually `observe`.

Comment: Where to validate the response in viewmodel or in view?

Answer (score 2):

From the documents

> You must call the setValue(T) method to update the LiveData object
>   from the main thread. If the code is executed in a worker thread, you
>   can use the postValue(T) method instead to update the LiveData object.

use

```
 loginResponse.postValue(response.body());
```

more detail refer  [LiveData Overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#java)

**Edit:**

In LoginRepository  remove

```
 final MutableLiveData<LoginResponse> loginResponse = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

set value to viewmodel LoginResponse then only new value pass viemodel to activity